# network UNCLAIMED with Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 after fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

Some useful information to help with diagnostics:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
25:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0084]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

**lshw**

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
```

**Kernel**

```
$ uname -r
5.15.0-41-generic
```

**dmesg**

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[  133.187211] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: pcim_iomap_regions_request_all failed
[  133.187224] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:25:00.0 failed with error -22
```

**System Info**

```
$ uname -a
Linux a25f126-lcedt 5.15.0-41-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 13:27:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

p.s. No dual boot. Ubuntu only, i.e., disabling Fast Startup in BIOS didn't help.

**Edit**

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep 25:00
[sudo] password for startup: 
[    2.214779] pci 0000:25:00.0: [8086:2723] type 00 class 0x028000
[    2.214811] pci 0000:25:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0500000-0xf0503fff 64bit]
[    2.214979] pci 0000:25:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    2.251872] pci 0000:25:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit]
[    2.251873] pci 0000:25:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit]
[    2.252073] pci 0000:25:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00004000 64bit]
[    2.252074] pci 0000:25:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000 64bit]
[    2.253941] pci 0000:25:00.0: Adding to iommu group 43
[   53.193450] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: pcim_iomap_regions_request_all failed
[   53.193473] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:25:00.0 failed with error -22
```

**After upgrade**

```
$ cat /proc/version_signature
Ubuntu 5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1-generic 5.15.53
```

```
$ uname -r
5.15.0-48-generic
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[   47.972918] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: pcim_iomap_regions_request_all failed
[   47.972929] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:25:00.0 failed with error -22
```

**Contents of /etc/default/grub**

```
$ more /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=assign-busses"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"
...
```

Then, I ran `$ sudo update-grub` and `$ sudo reboot`. Unfortunately, the dmesg output didn't change.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[   28.553306] iwlwifi 0000:26:00.0: pcim_iomap_regions_request_all failed
[   28.553320] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:26:00.0 failed with error -22
```

Comment: @chili555 is this something that you can help, please?

Comment: I'm working on it. I'll post back as soon as/if I find something.

Comment: May we please see the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep 25:00` in an edit to your question? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, the latest kernel version is -48 and you are running -41. If you update and reboot, is the problem resolved? `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 I added the output of `sudo dmesg | grep 25:00`, and I ran `apt get update` and `apt get upgrade`. Now I am working on upgrading the kernel/

Comment: upgrade should bring you to -48 after a reboot.

Comment: @chili555 yes, it did. however, I am still seeing an error when I run `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298397/ubuntu-sees-only-one-of-two-nvme-drives-that-are-visible-to-bios-and-windows-10 `pci=assign-busses` I will write a step-by-step in a few hours unless, of course, you are confident that you understand the process.

Comment: Particularly note the comments on chili555's  1298397 link about updating firmware.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same issue and adding pci=assign-busses doesn't seem to do anything on my setup.

Comment: I am very sorry that I have no further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the technique mentioned in the link I gave above. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

In the editor window, use the arrow keys to move the cursor to the line beginning with "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT". Change that line to read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=assign-busses"
```

Proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor nano. Follow with:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thanks, I am working on it right now.

Comment: I completed these steps, please see the contents of my `/etc/default/grub` file above. I rebooted the machine, but unfortunately the Wi-Fi is still not working. I was thinking that since `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` is defined (and assigned to a different value) after `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, it might be used instead of the default parameter. Should I modify `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` too?

Comment: No,just the default line needs modification. Are the dmesg errors changed?

Comment: Unfortunately, no change with dmesg error. (Sorry for delay, I didn't have access to the machine over the weekend.)

Comment: Do the AX200 drivers come with my kernel version? Maybe I should download AX200 firmware from here (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) and `mv` the `.ucode` file to `/lib/firmware/`. Let me know what you think :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to you, or anyone else that comes after. But I stumbled upon a fix that worked for me.

My setup:

- ASUS Pro WS WRX80E Sage Wifi Motherboard with Intel AX200 Wifi builtin
- Ubuntu 20.10 (5.19.0-23-generic kernel)

I installed `linux-modules-iwlwifi-generic`, which didn't get Wifi working (was still getting pcim_iomap_regions_request_all failed and error -22). Looking into pcim_iomap_regions_request_all it seems like there was an issue with memory allocation. That led me to wonder if there was something hardware related preventing it from properly allocating memory. I went into bios and found a setting "Re-Size BAR Support" under PCI Settings. Clearing motherboard CMOS + Enabling "Re-size BAR Support" finally got my adapter working!