Struggling to get wifi driver to work on asus ws wrx80e sage se wifi
I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 24.04 and am unable to get the Wifi driver to work. It worked once (in recovery mode) and I don't seem to be able to do that anymore.
Here is the output of lspci -knn | grep -iA3 net
24:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller X550 [8086:1563] (rev 01)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Controller X550 [1043:8712]
Kernel driver in use: ixgbe
Kernel modules: ixgbe
24:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller X550 [8086:1563] (rev 01)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Controller X550 [1043:8712]
Kernel driver in use: ixgbe
Kernel modules: ixgbe
25:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E(802.11ax) AX210/AX1675* 2x2 [Typhoon Peak] [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
26:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1061/ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:0612] (rev 02)

The output of sudo dmesg |grep iwlwifi is
[   13.122574] iwlwifi_compat: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   13.124393] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   13.124395] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:11510:0106cce5
[   13.200648] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: pcim_iomap_regions_request_all failed
[   13.200659] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:25:00.0 failed with error -22

I uninstalled and reinstalled linux-modules-iwlwifi-generic and don't see any change.
I have disabled Resizable bar in the BIOS settings, installed linux-generic and am currently out of ideas. I still get the "No Wifi Adapter Found"

Does this answer your question? AX210 wifi not working on Ubuntu21.04

Power the computer down, remove power cord, then press and hold power button for 30 seconds, assemble and boot

Tried this out. Still the same issue. The only difference in the dmesg | grep iwlwifi output is: [   23.200648] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: pcim_iomap_regions_request_all failed
[   23.200659] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:25:00.0 failed with error -22

Is Windows 10 or 11 installed?

No, there is no windows installed.

See this answer and see if your BIOS has that option https://askubuntu.com/a/1438335/300665

Tried that too. Set bar resizing to auto. Made no difference.

What graphics on that computer?

An NVIDIA RTX 3090

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server on ASUS Pro WS WRX80E SAGE SE WIFI.
Edit the grub file:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Make the following change:
# add to either GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT or GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
# for example:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amd-iommu=on iommu=pt pci=nommconf"

Then run:
sudo update-grub

and reboot.
Then when looking at iwlwifi messages in the kernel ring buffer, I see the following:
[MASKED]@[MASKED]:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[sudo] password for [MASKED]: 
[    7.406524] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.418086] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x[MASKED], cnv-id 0x[MASKED] wfpm id 0x[MASKED]
[    7.418095] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: PCI dev 2723/0084, rev=0x340, rfid=0x10a100
[    7.421402] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    7.421816] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: loaded firmware version 77.ad46c98b.0 cc-a0-77.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.595684] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    7.717872] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    7.783467] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: base HW address: [MASKED]
[    7.798925] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0 wlp37s0: renamed from wlan0
[    8.440962] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 1

Please note that you may want to turn off the VGA onboard controller switch.
For more information, see the following personal notes I keep about how to fix issues with this motherboard.
